# How to get updated positions in Lua

Tags: lua, collision-detection

I have 2 classes, In one class, I have code for position of object1 changing with time and in class2, I have code for object2 changing with time, the positions are changing continuously at different rates. Now, I want to figure out if the two objects collide, but how do I get their positions that are changing at difference of less tahn a second, is their any shortcut or efficient method to do that?

Here is how object1 and object 2 are changing their positions:

```
object 1:
self:setRotation( self:getRotation() + math.random(5,7) )

object2:
x = 215 + math.cos(angle)*195 
y = 130 + math.sin(angle)*115
```

Both of these are part of 2 different classes. I need to use them in a third lua file where I am checking for the collisions, so how can I get x and y value of both of these as soon as it changes and pass them to a new function to check for collisions

I have 2 classes, In one class, I have code for position of object1 changing with time and in class2, I have code for object2 changing with time, the positions are changing continuously at different rates. Now, I want to figure out if the two objects collide, but how do I get their positions that are changing at difference of less tahn a second, is their any shortcut or efficient method to do that?

Here is how object1 and object 2 are changing their positions:

```
object 1:
self:setRotation( self:getRotation() + math.random(5,7) )

object2:
x = 215 + math.cos(angle)*195 
y = 130 + math.sin(angle)*115
```

Both of these are part of 2 different classes. I need to use them in a third lua file where I am checking for the collisions, so how can I get x and y value of both of these as soon as it changes and pass them to a new function to check for collisions

Here is how I tried to use Collision detection using TNT

--> let's say I group all my 3 clock hands, these are rotated around an anchor point so x and y remain the same, but they have some width extending,

--> My player is moving in an ellipsis and it's position is changing with time(only when the player jumps, it's not on floor)

Requirement--> what I really want is whenever the player touches any of the clock hands, youLoose method(not given in the code) shall be called, now to achieve this, here is what I did: 
and the collision can be anywhere across the length of any of the clock hands,(so basically this part is what I am not getting)
I checked collision as soon as x and y of player changed,here is the code:
attaching the image as well

```
x = 215 + math.cos(angle)*195 
y = 130 + math.sin(angle)*115 
for i = 1, groupA:getNumChildren() do
local sprite2 = groupA:getChildAt(i) 
local oBoxToObox = tntCollision.oBoxToObox
if i == 1 then 
a = 97
b = 11 
elseif i == 2 then 
a = 206
b = 64
else 
a = 120
b = 10
end
local pointToObox = tntCollision.pointToObox
tntCollision.setCollisionAnchorPoint(0, 0)
if oBoxToObox(x,y, 36, 40, cute.anim[self.frame]: getRotation(),sprite2:getX(), sprite2:getY(), a ,b, sprite2:getRotation()) then 
youLoose()
end
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the objects have volume you need to test if their boundaries cross, quite complicated, and you should use either Box2d or TNT Collision. Both integrated to Gideros (although TNT is a separate download). TNT Collision is only collision, no physics, so likely to be faster but not necessarily so, you would have to compare.

Otherwise (no volume, ie just point collisions), you can just test the x coordinate of each object; if almost identical, then check the y coord; if almost identical you have a collision, otherwise you don't.

Comment: The objects do have volumes, Is there any method in gideros to get the boundaries?

Comment: TNT I tried to use and for some reason it is not detecting collision, I thought it should but the problem is kind of different, updating the question

Comment: Updated the question, have a look please